According to Catholic theology, did Eve have Original Sin, or only her own personal sin?
If Original Sin is Adam's sin, did Eve have Original Sin? If so, then how did she "catch" it from Adam? Or is her (and women's) punishment in Gen. 3:16 only due to her actual sin of pride, and not to her having Original Sin?
cf. "Did Original Sin derive solely from Adam or from both Adam and Eve?"

Neither Adam nor Eve were initially sinful. They became sinful in the Fall (i.e. the events of Genesis 3:1-7). Strictly speaking, "Original Sin" (that is, inherited sin) only applies to their descendants.
Note that some Christians believe that Original Sin is passed on by the male; thus, Jesus Christ, having been conceived by the Holy Spirit rather than a human male, was without inherited sin.
So... Eve (and Adam) only had "actual" sin (i.e. those which they themselves committed). All other humans, except Christ, having fathers who are [descendants of] Adam, inherit Original Sin.

Indeed, "Eve was in the transgression" and "through one man sin entered the world".  Concise and accurate. +1

"Some Christians believe that Original Sin is passed on by the male" but not really Catholics afaik? We believe that Mary was also born without Original Sin, that wouldn't make much sense if the sin was only passed down by the father.

@Yksisarvinen, I don't actually know who "some Christians" are; it's definitely a hypothesis I've encountered, but I don't know that it tends to follow any denominational lines. (Aside from, as you rightly note, "not Roman Catholics".)
